# My App has no Client ID?

Tags: android, google-play, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

So I'm using the Unreal Engine 4 to make a mobile game. I'm currently trying to set up the Google Play services so I can do Leaderboards, Acheivements and In-App Purchases, but I'm struggling with the first right now.

You can see the behaviour in this [short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uuK2fWnkJvQ).

It seems that it tries to contact the service then something goes wrong and it gives up. I made a logcat logfile from my phone while this was happening and this is what I got:

```
I/GamesNativeSDK(16078): Connecting to Google Play...

V/GamesNativeSDK(16078): Attached to JVM on thread main_dispatch

D/ChimeraCfgMgr(11916): Loading module com.google.android.gms.games from APK com.google.android.play.games

D/ChimeraModuleLdr(11916): Module APK com.google.android.play.games already loaded

D/ChimeraCfgMgr(11916): Loading module com.google.android.gms.games from APK com.google.android.play.games

D/ChimeraModuleLdr(11916): Module APK com.google.android.play.games already loaded

V/GamesNativeSDK(16078): Play Games callback indicates connection failure.

I/GamesNativeSDK(16078): UI interaction required to connect to Google Play.

D/UE4     (16078): [2015.10.26-19.31.29:804][  0]LogOnline:Warning: Async task 'Login' failed in 0.582350 seconds

E/SignInIntentService(11916): Access Not Configured. The API (Google Play Game Services API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.

E/SignInIntentService(11916): com.google.android.gms.games.server.error.GamesException

E/SignInIntentService(11916):  at com.google.android.gms.games.server.GamesServer.getResponseBlocking(GamesServer.java:164)

E/SignInIntentService(11916):  at com.google.android.gms.games.broker.PlayerAgent.getPlayerFromNetwork(PlayerAgent.java:1700)

E/SignInIntentService(11916):  at com.google.android.gms.games.broker.PlayerAgent.fetchPlayer(PlayerAgent.java:621)

E/SignInIntentService(11916):  at com.google.android.gms.games.broker.DataBroker.loadSelf(DataBroker.java:920)

E/SignInIntentService(11916):  at com.google.android.gms.games.service.PlayGamesSignInIntentService$LoadSelfOperation.executeInternal(PlayGamesSignInIntentService.java:402)

E/SignInIntentService(11916):  at com.google.android.gms.games.service.PlayGamesSignInIntentService$BaseOperation.execute(PlayGamesSignInIntentService.java:51)

E/SignInIntentService(11916):  at com.google.android.gms.games.service.PlayGamesSignInIntentService$OperationAdapter.execute(PlayGamesSignInIntentService.java:487)

E/SignInIntentService(11916):  at com.google.android.gms.chimera.BaseAsyncOperationService$OperationTask.run(BaseAsyncOperationService.java:179)

E/SignInIntentService(11916):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)

E/SignInIntentService(11916):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)

E/SignInIntentService(11916):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

E/LoadSelfFragment(16219): Unable to sign in - application does not have a registered client ID
```

I understand the error messages, but I don't understand why I get them. I tried to Deploy directly from the launcher as well as make a signed APK and install on my phone. It's the same result.

I looked around for a solution to this issue but I can't find any problems with the settings in my Developer Console nor anything missing. I'm a bit at a loss here and I'm aiming for a release in December 2015 so I need help. Epic Games had pretty much no documentation on the nodes provided to do this so all of this have been me fumbling in the dark.

[image: First Part]

[image: Second Part]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much struggle and fumbling in the dark I've now found the solution myself. Please follow [this link](https://forums.unrealengine.com/showthread.php?89563-Integrate-Google-Play-Services-with-Blueprint&p=409314) to the Unreal Forums to check out how I did it!

The basic gist of it is:

Make sure the following APIs are unlocked in your developer console:

- Google Cloud Messaging for Android
- Google Cloud Pub/Sub
- Google Cloud User Accounts
- Google Play Android Developer API
- Google Play Game Management
- Google Play Game Services
- Google+ API

Make sure you have a public server key in your credentials with no IP's in the IP list.

Add the following two lines to the `<manifest>` part of the project settings.

- com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID="@string/app_id"
- com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID="@string/app_id"

Then add all of these permissions to the `Extra Permissions` part of the project

- com.android.vending.BILLING (only if you have in-app purchases)
- android.permission.INTERNET
- android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
- android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS

Open up the build folder and in the `GooglePlayAppID.xml` found at `<PROJECT NAME>\Build\Android\res\values` add your apps ID

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_id">YOUR GAMES APP ID HERE</string>
</resources>
```

Now you should be able to use the nodes provided by Epic to make Achievements, Leaderboards and In-app purchases work.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I changed the answer. Is that better? :)

Comment: Yup.It's much better this way.

Answer (score 1):

Another essential step (which is in the Unreal Forum link) is the following addition to YourProject.build.cs:

```
if (Target.Platform == UnrealTargetPlatform.Android)
{
    PrivateDependencyModuleNames.Add("OnlineSubsystem");
    PrivateDependencyModuleNames.Add("OnlineSubsystemGooglePlay");
}
```

Source: https://forums.unrealengine.com/showthread.php?67343-How-do-I-debug-refusal-to-connecto-to-Google-Play-services

(onlineSubsystem might be required for other platforms, such as Windows/Steam)

Comment: You can only do that if you build it yourself, but yes you are correct. Mine was just pure blueprint ^^